# Div inside another div not floating right

Tags: html, css

I have a top div with some text floated to the left and a div floated right that contains an ad image, social media links, and a search box. My search box is not floating right even though it is in it's own div that I have set to float right. It also appears my ad is not floating right. Also, my social media icons are showing up backwards. Many thanks for the help.

```
#gsc-control-cse form.gsc-search-box    { float:right; width: 200px; }
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pgk0k757/7/)

Image of what site looks like when I preview is [here](http://postimg.org/image/bbcabvgg3/)

Comment: Don't give us your whole page and then expect us to work it out. You need to provide the *minimal* amount of code to replicate the error. Go back to your fiddle and start stripping bits out until you have the absolute minimum you can and still produce the error. Use example content, don't put broken images in etc.

Comment: give me a minute please

Comment: ok it's been updated

Comment: What do you want it to look like, it is hard to tell what specifically you want changed

Comment: I want the ad image, social media links, and search box all on top of one another and all floated right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the float right on the inner elements and remove the width 70% on #top-right

```
#top-right {
  float: right;
}
#top-right ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#gsc-control-cse form.gsc-search-box {
  width: 200px;
}
```